# How do I calculate the coordinate of an object in canvas after rotation?

Tags: javascript, rotation

Please see the image below.

[image]

I know that angle of rotation is about 30 degrees, but how do I find location of point `x` after the rotation? Also, the rotation could be a 360 degree, full circle rotation.

Maybe I should be using Math.sin/cos/atan etc?

Comment: Rotate what? Rotate base on which point?

Comment: ups sorry, i forget to mention that.
rotate base is on center point (see "before rotation" state, far right)